# python artifactory library: create folders on repository and authenticate without pass the password

Tags: python, artifactory

I am using the python library to interact with the artifactory repository; so far so good if I pass the credentials and I upload a file.

```
path = ArtifactoryPath("http://myartifactory/myrepo/", auth=('tester', 'thepassword'))
path.deploy_file("/tmp/test.zip")
```

But if I try to upload a folder I get an error, and I can't see any method to upload a folder, unless you zip it and upload it as file.

`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`

Also the command `path.mkdir()` does not seem to do what it say; I did try to pass also a string for the folder name, but it won't create a folder on the atifactory repository.

`FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists:`

And I am also looking for a way to not hardcode the auth credentials, since it would not be nice to share a password in clear. the library mention that it accept a certificate as `.pem` file, but I am not sure how do you create such certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload folders directly, they have to be in an archive as per [the docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactsfromArchive):

> Supported archive types are: zip; tar; tar.gz; and tgz.

To create a directory, you can simply pass a [path with the directory you want](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateDirectory).

A `.pem` file is used to hold your RSA Public Key, and could be generate with:

`ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -m 'PEM' -e > public.pem
chmod 600 public.pem`